# mongo-connector oplog timestamp and mongodb_meta time stamps not in sync

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

`mongo_connector` creates a `mongodb_meta` index that stores the `time_stamp` of the document inserted/modified.

There is a function in the source [here](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/elastic2-doc-manager/blob/master/mongo_connector/doc_managers/elastic2_doc_manager.py#L298) which shows how to get the most recently modified document by its timestamp.

There is also an oplog timestamp which syncs with the input mongo collection.

I noticed even when both the mongodb and elasticsearch are synced, the timestamps of the most recent changes are not same.

When I run this command:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/mongodb_meta/mongodb_meta/_search" -d '{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": [{
        "_ts": "desc"
    }],
    "size": 1
}'
```

I get a document with timestamp with timestamp as `6269823168853049445` which is `Mon Apr  4 17:56:04 2016` but the `oplog.timestamp`, that the monog-connector maintains, has the latest sync timestamp as `6270075841779073025` which is `Tue Apr  5 10:16:34 2016`.

I thought of refreshing the index but that does not always give me the correct results. Like I refreshed the index 24 hours ago and I was getting instant results at time but I have been refreshing it over the last hour and it still gives the result that I was getting yesterday.
There are nearly ~150 million documents in `mongodb_meta`.

I also submitted a range query to get documents having timestamps greater than `6269823168853049445`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "_ts": {
                        "gt": 6269823168853049445
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which gives 0 hits.

I don't understand where am I going wrong?